# Custom Draw in NSView without erasing the previous background

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, nsview

I am trying to plot few points dynamically on my Custom View using Quartz functions so that i get a complete graph. I handle drawing of lines inside the drawRect method of Custom View where I get the current context and draw the lines. But, they get erased when i try to draw a new line. I want to have those lines also visible along with the new ones drawn. Please let me know how to do this. I can't store all the points together and draw at the end. I want to continously update my view. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your custom view:

```
- (BOOL) isOpaque { return YES; }
```

That will prevent the drawing of any views behind yours including the background.

Note, however, that on resize you'll need to redraw everything either way. A more proper solution would be to use off-screen image to draw into instead.

Comment: Thanks. That was what i was looking for.  By off-screen image drawing, you mean to say, that I should get a NSBitmapImageRep object, keep drawing in that and display it on the current graphics context. Is it what you meant or am I understanding something incorrectly.

Comment: Does the following steps mean "Offscreen Drawing"? Having a NSImageView, creating a new context using "CGBitmapContextCreate", drawing whatever i want to on that context, creating a NSBitmapImageRep out of it, then a NSImage and setting it to the view using setImage?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CALayers:  add a new child layer to the root each time you have new data, and draw to that layer.  Your drawing code can remain the same:  you just need to put in the code for creating and using layers, which is actually pretty easy.
See:   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514

Comment: Is it a good practice to have n number of layers? I might have to draw around 100 child layers in this case. Is it ok?

Comment: I've read that you can have thousands of layers on the screen at once, so it shouldn't be a problem.  However, if you are just creating a composite image, and don't need the flexibility that layers might provide, Simon's suggestion is probably the way to go.